# Preserve attributes when copying a file in Raku

Tags: raku

On the cli, in linux, `cp -p` preserves the modified/accessed timestamps on a file. Is it possible to do the same directly in Raku?

The Rosetta example uses Nativecall and it could be done with a system call but looks like these timestamps are only readable in Raku. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm checking the code path and it goes pertty much straight to `nqp::copy` https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/7406f8c6270fac51b14da272fe9061b03c1d904b/src/core.c/IO/Path.pm6#L464 I'll try and see what we have there, only once it gets there it's not easy to follow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This operation is supported at the virtual machine level by the [`nqp::copy`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/7406f8c6270fac51b14da272fe9061b03c1d904b/src/core.c/IO/Path.pm6#L464) op, which eventually goes down to [`MVM_file_copy`](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/blob/8d7a80d55791ed851dd000e02c2939737fe0075b/src/io/fileops.c#L135-L148) at the MoarVM level, which defers to the equivalent operation in [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/fs.html), which, well, it does not support that, as [pointed out in this nodejs issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/15793). So no, you're not missing anything, except maybe [`copy`](https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Path#routine_copy) could be better documented.

Comment: Great, thanks for that deep dive. I thought not, but was fishing for more info. I've done it through `run` to access the underling system command.